# Error on adding a map marker with tomtom sdk

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tomtom

#### Leaflet library error

I get this error every time I try to add a map marker to my map

leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function at i.addTo (leaflet.js:5).  This function is part of the library and I have no clue why it doesn't work. My code comes from the developers portal at tomtom. Here is my code.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='sdk/map.css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src='sdk/tomtom.min.js'></script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class="name-header">
    <div class="name-wrapper">
   <nav class="container">

   </nav>
</div>
</header>
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="svgbox">

            </div>
       </div>

           <div id="map"> </div>


 <script>
     var storeLocation = [35.677512,-81.99855]

 const map =   tomtom.setProductInfo('KG\'s', '<your-product- 
 version>');
        tomtom.L.map("map", {
        key: 'myapikey',
                source: 'vector',
                center: storeLocation,
                basePath: '/sdk',
                zoom: 15


      });

   var marker = tomtom.L.marker(storeLocation).addTo(map);
   marker.bindPopup("my business").openPopup();

</script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My map size is declared in my css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned *map* to a what is returned from setProductInfo method.
It should be assigned to tomtom.L.map.

```
const map = tomtom.L.map("map", {
    key: 'myapikey',
    source: 'vector',
    center: storeLocation,
    basePath: '/sdk',
    zoom: 15
});
```

Comment: There are also smaller issues like semicolon missing, bad indents, tags closed but don't see opening tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar:

```
const map = tomtom.L.map("map", {
    key: 'YOUR API KEY',
    center: [0.0000, 00.0000],
    basePath: 'tomtom',
    zoom: 16
});
var marker = tomtom.L.marker([0.0000, 00.0000]).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup('Flyover International').openPopup();
```